# Filter a list by item index?

Tags: scala

```
val data = List("foo", "bar", "bash")
val selection = List(0, 2)
val selectedData = data.filter(datum => selection.contains(datum.MYINDEX))
//                                                  INVALID CODE HERE ^
// selectedData: List("foo", "bash")
```

Say I want to filter a `List` given a list of selected indices. If, in the `filter` method, I could reference the index of a list item then I could solve this as above, but `datum.MYINDEX` isn't valid in the above case.

How could I do this instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using `zipWithIndex` to keep a reference to the item's index, filtering as such, then mapping the index away?

```
data.zipWithIndex
    .filter{ case (datum, index) => selection.contains(index) }
    .map(_._1)
```

Comment: one final point (after actually reading the link you gave) is that your quote mining - the bracketing debate was the age old Egyptian bracketing argument, which in languages like Java is *optional* (in Scala it is not). Now I'm not aware of ANY language where it is OK to put a statement/expression on the *same line* as the opening bracket, that is objectively wrong, NOT personal preference.

Comment: The only thing I concede is that the guide is a little implicit about this, and the space before brace problem, and only explicitly states that closing braces should be on it's own line ".. the closing brace is on its own line immediately following the last line of the function".  Therefore I'll edit one last time, according to the explicit, objectively true, part of the style guide, and leave all the implicit mistakes up to you.

Comment: @samthebest, there are a lot of different formatting tools and settings. Why do you insist on using a specific one?

Comment: @Basilevs Because that's what the style guide says you should use. Yes it's possible to change the settings to use a 50 space indent, but that is wrong, in Scala it's 2 spaces.  Freedom to change a setting is not equal to the resulting setting being acceptable.

Comment: @samthebest, why don't you post a link to the guide then?

Comment: That reminds me, the indentation is objectively wrong, http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/indentation.html

Comment: @samthebest - Coding and indentation style are up to the answerer, and we should defer to their preferences. If the answerer does not want your changes, don't force them on them. Accept that they have a difference of style and move on.

Answer (score 1):

It's neater to do it the other way about (although potentially slow with Lists as indexing is slow (O(n)). Vectors would be better. On the other hand, the `contains` of the other solution for every item in `data` isn't exactly fast)

```
val data = List("foo", "bar", "bash")
         //> data  : List[String] = List(foo, bar, bash)
val selection = List(0, 2)  
         //> selection  : List[Int] = List(0, 2)
selection.map(index=>data(index))
         //> res0: List[String] = List(foo, bash)
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if you have an index which is greater than the size of the `data` list.

Comment: Yes. The OP can say whether or not that's an issue and what the behaviour should be for an invalid index.

Comment: It depends. `val x = List(1); x(1)` will throw an exception. I don't see this as very different, it's just we've been handed a list of indices, not just one

Answer (score 0):

First solution that came to my mind was to create a list of pairs (element, index), filter every element by checking if selection contains that index, then map resulting list in order to keep only raw elementd (omit index). Code is self explanatory:

```
data.zipWithIndex.filter(pair => selection.contains(pair._2)).map(_._1)
```

or more readable:

```
val elemsWithIndices = data.zipWithIndex
val filteredPairs = elemsWithIndices.filter(pair => selection.contains(pair._2))
val selectedElements = filteredPairs.map(_._1)
```

Comment: Maybe the 2nd is more readible to someone with like 2 days of Scala experience, but the first way is so idiomatic most Scala devs would prefer it for its elegance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of indices already, the most efficient way is to pick those indices directly:

```
val data = List("foo", "bar", "bash")
val selection = List(0, 2)
val selectedData = selection.map(index => data(index))
```

or even:

```
val selectedData = selection.map(data)
```

or if you need to preserve the order of the items in data:

```
val selectedData = selection.sorted.map(data)
```

**UPDATED**

In the spirit of finding all the possible algorithms, here's the version using `collect`:

```
val selectedData = data
  .zipWithIndex
  .collect { 
    case (item, index) if selection.contains(index) => item 
   }
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if you have an index which is greater than the size of the `data` list.

Comment: But maybe an exception is the required behaviour. Just like doing a simple single index of the List with an over-large index.

Comment: Or even even `val selectedData = selection map data`

Comment: These "code-golf" type questions are amazingly popular!

Comment: note, that the first snippet wouldn't be *efficient* from performance POV for large lists: List lookups are O(N)

Comment: @om-nom-nom Yeah, Paul mentioned that in his answer. A sort/merge algorithm occurs to me: `selection.sort.iterator.buffered` + foldLeft with an accumulator that keeps track of the current index.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Would `val a = data.toArray ; selection.map(a)` improve `List` O(N) lookup ?

Answer (score 0):

This Works :

```
val data = List("foo", "bar", "bash")
val selection = List(0, 2)
val selectedData = data.filter(datum => selection.contains(data.indexOf(datum)))
println (selectedData)
```

output : 
List(foo, bash)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the probably most scalable way to do it in terms of efficiency, and unlike many answers on SO, actually follows the official scala style guide exactly.

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashSet

val selectionSet = new HashSet() ++ selection

data.zipWithIndex.collect { 
  case (datum, index) if selectionSet.contains(index) => datum
}
```

If the resulting collection is to be passed to additional `map`, `flatMap`, etc, suggest turning `data` into a lazy sequence.  In fact perhaps you should do this anyway in order to avoid 2-passes, one for the `zipWithIndex` one for the `collect`, but I doubt when benchmarked one would gain much.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an easier way to filter by index using the `map` method. Here is an example

```
val indices = List(0, 2)
val data = List("a", "b", "c")

println(indices.map(data)) // will print List("a", "c")
```