# How can I explain the Apache Spark RDD Lineage Graph?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have few question with this below code:

```
val input1 = rawinput.map(_.split("\t")).map(x=>(x(6).trim(),x)).sortByKey()
val input2 = input1.map(x=> x._2.mkString("\t"))
val x0 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(0))
val x1 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(1))
val x2 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(2))
val x3 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(3))
val x4 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(4))
val x5 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(5))
val x6 = input2.map(_.split("\t")).map(x => (x(6),x(6))
val x = x0 union x1 union x2 union  x3 union x4 union x5 union x6


<pre>
**Lineage Graph:**
(7) UnionRDD[25] at union at rddCustUtil.scala:78 []
|  UnionRDD[24] at union at rddCustUtil.scala:78 []
|  UnionRDD[23] at union at rddCustUtil.scala:78 []
|  UnionRDD[22] at union at rddCustUtil.scala:78 []
|  UnionRDD[21] at union at rddCustUtil.scala:78 []
|  UnionRDD[20] at union at rddCustUtil.scala:78 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:43 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[6] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:43 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:48 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[8] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:48 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[11] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:53 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:53 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[13] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:58 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[12] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:58 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[15] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:63 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[14] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:63 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[17] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:68 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[16] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:68 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[19] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:73 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[18] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:73 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
</pre>
```

- Can you please explain me how many shuffle stage will be executed as it is showing 7 ShuffledRDD[4]?
- Can you please give me details explanation below DAG flow?
- Is this operation expensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how many shuffle stage will be executed

Indeed, the shuffle required to sort your data happens 7 times, because Spark's evaluation is lazy and runs on-demand, and unless **cached** it will be recomputed for every branch in the DAG that requires it. To solve this (and make this calculation much faster, probably), you can **cache** (or, more generally, **persist**) `input2` before you use it multiple times:

```
val input1 = rawinput.map(_.split("\t")).map(x=>(x(6).trim(),x)).sortByKey()
val input2 = input1.map(x=> x._2.mkString("\t")).cache()
// continue as before
```

> Can you please give me details explanation below DAG flow

Each of your `x_` RDDs is calculated "separately" using the following calculation:

```
+-(1) MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
    |  /Data/ MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
    |  /Data/ HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at rddCustUtil.scala:35 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:48 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[8] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:48 []
|  MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at rddCustUtil.scala:40 []
|  ShuffledRDD[4] at sortByKey at rddCustUtil.scala:38 []
```

Which shows the calculation that created `rawinput` from textFile, and then the sorting and the three `map` operations.

Then, you have 6 union operations unioining these 7 RDDs.

> Is this operation expensive?

**YES**, it seems like it would be. As suggested above, caching can make it much faster - but there's a better way to achieve this - *without splitting the RDD into many separate ones*:

```
val x = rawinput.map(_.split("\t"))
  .keyBy(_(6).trim()) // extract key
  .flatMap{ case (k, arr) => arr.take(7).zipWithIndex.map((k, _)) } // flatMap into (key, (value, index))
  .sortBy { case (k, (_, index)) => (index, k) } // sort by index first, key second
  .map    { case (k, (value, _)) => (k, value) } // remove index, it was just used for sorting
```

This will perform a single shuffle operation, and won't require persisting the data. The DAG would look like this:

```
(4) MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at Test.scala:75 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[8] at sortBy at Test.scala:74 []
 |  ShuffledRDD[7] at sortBy at Test.scala:74 []
 +-(4) MapPartitionsRDD[4] at sortBy at Test.scala:74 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[3] at flatMap at Test.scala:73 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[2] at keyBy at Test.scala:72 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at Test.scala:71 []
    |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at Test.scala:64 []
```

Comment: Much appreciated Tzach, But in case if I use cache or persists method then how many shuffle require to sort the data?

Comment: One, I believe. The print-out might not reflect the fact that the shuffle stage will be _skipped_ thanks to the caching.

Comment: Hi Tzach, I have one question on the below staement:

Comment: .flatMap{ case (k, arr) => arr.take(7).zipWithIndex.map((k, _)) }. You have used arr.take(7), suppose, I have list of index like List(1, 3, 4, 5, 6) then how can I select only the selected list index.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630475/filter-a-list-by-item-index

Comment: But Tzach, in this post index sequence number has been changed. Suppose, I am passing index in this format 3,2,6,2,8, it should keep maintain the state. It is always giving me acceding order.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, perhaps it belongs in a separate post. Wouldn't `.flatMap{ case (k, arr) => arr.zipWithIndex.filter(t => colIndices.contains(t._2)).map((k, _)) }` work, assuming `colIndices = List(3,2,6,2,8)`?

Comment: Thank you @Tzach, Can you please help me other solution: Suppose, I have RDD 'Array[(String, (String, String))] = Array((1001,("764839","id","q")), (1001,("Souvik","fnm","p")), (1001,("Das","lnm","p")), (1002,("764840","pid","q")), (1002,("Palash","fnm","p")), ("1002",("Mandal","lnm","p")))' The format is like: '(ROW_KEY,("VALUE","COLUMN_QUALIFIER","COLUMN_FAMILY"))' but I want this format '[ROW_KEY, Map[COLUMN_FAMILY, Array[(COLUMN_QUALIFIER, (VALUE, TIMESTAMP))]])]' Can you please help me to get this?

Comment: That's not what comments are for - if you have another question, post a new question.